# How to import submodules from relative path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I have multiple modules in my project and specify some execution point. But when I try to import files from submodules, it doesn't work.

So, how to specify submodules to execute from selected execution file?

```
project
--bin
---- executeFile
--modules
---- __init__.py
----fileA.py
```

in `executeFile`, I try:

```
from ..modules.fileA import *
```

but get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./bin/muexecute", line 10, in <module>
  from ..modules.os import *
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Comment: have you tried  from modules.os import * ?

Comment: Yes, but get error: ImportError: No module named 'modules'. As far as I understand from documentation, bin and modules are different module directories, so I need some entry point or\and hack to allow that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution.
The problem was in my opinion about using **init**.py.
I placed in executable scripts path to including and it works fine

```
PACKAGE_PARENT = '..'
SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.expanduser(__file__))))
sys.path.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, PACKAGE_PARENT)))
```

Answer (score 0):

All modules you want to import should in in your PYTHONPATH. Therefore there is no hierarchy.
In your case It seems to me that an `__init__.py` is missing from your project's main folder (with all the models included), so executefile doesn't know about your modules.

Comment: What? The PYTHONPATH one or the `__init__.py` one?

Answer (score 0):

So you are having trouble defining your relative path, correct? Try the following:

```
from sys import path
path.append('C:\\realative_path')
from function_file import required_function
```

Hope that helps.